# Explain please portmapping for GitLab at docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, mapping

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html
I am reading documentation and I am curious:

Should it be similar to `:22`. Like this: `:80`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following lines configure GitLab for HTTP port `8929` and SSH port `2224` within the container.

```yaml
environment:
  GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
    external_url "http://gitlab.example.com:8929"
    gitlab_rails["gitlab_shell_ssh_port"] = 2224
```

The `ports:` section of the `docker-compose.yml` file maps a host port to a container port in the form: `- 'HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT'`.

In this particular example, the HTTP port is being mapped to host port `8929`, and the GitLab Shell SSH port is mapped to host port `2224`.

See, [Docker Docs: Compose file reference, ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports).

Comment: yes, I know that. But gitlab does not expose `8929` port, so we can not map it. So I do not understand. How we can map not exposed port.

Comment: The port is being exposed to the host by the line `-8929:8929` in `docker-compose.yml`. Inside the container, we are telling GitLab to use port `8929` with line: `external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com:8929'`

Comment: Probably I explain bad. I mean `gitlab` has no service on port 8929. How we can expose it?

Comment: I'm telling you that it is configured to have the HTTP service at port 8929 because of the first line of the `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` environment variable sets up the HTTP service on port 8929.